# Filebeat sends only a part of logs to logstash when low persistance queue size. How to fix it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I am sending 25000 logs from filebeat to elasticsearch and another http server (spring boot) using filebeat and logstash. To send logs to two places, I use logstash [pipeline to pipeline communication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html) mechanism with [output isolator pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#output-isolator-pattern). But the problem is filebeat does not send all logs instead, just send 5000 logs and in the debug log it shows as below.

**Filebeat debug log**

```
2019-05-29T15:39:46.993+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/ackloop.go:160 ackloop: receive ack [295: 0, 1]
2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/eventloop.go:226   handle ACKs: 1
2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/eventloop.go:251   try ack index: (idx=0, i=0, seq=296)

2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/eventloop.go:269   broker ACK events: count=1, start-seq=296, end-seq=296

2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/eventloop.go:228   handle ACK took: 130.793µs
2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/ackloop.go:128 ackloop: return ack to broker loop:1
2019-05-29T15:39:46.994+0530    DEBUG   [monitoring]    memqueue/ackloop.go:131 ackloop:  done send ack
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:152  Run input
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:174    Start next scan
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404    Check file for harvesting: /home/nishan/Documents/input_logs/request-response-logger.log
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494    Update existing file for harvesting: /home/nishan/Documents/input_logs/request-response-logger.log, offset: 33311469
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:546    Harvester for file is still running: /home/nishan/Documents/input_logs/request-response-logger.log
2019-05-29T15:39:47.134+0530    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:195    input states cleaned up. Before: 1, After: 1, Pending: 0
```

Below are the configurations in filebeat and logstash.

**pipeline.yml**

```
- pipeline.id: intake
  queue.type: persisted
  config.string: |
    input { beats { port => 5043 } }
    output { pipeline { send_to => [spring, es_out] } }

- pipeline.id: spring
  queue.type: persisted
  path.config: "/home/nishan/Documents/logstash-config/spring.conf"
  queue.max_bytes: 15mb

- pipeline.id: elastic
  queue.type: persisted
  path.config: "/home/nishan/Documents/json_push/configurations/elastic.conf"
  queue.max_bytes: 500mb
```

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/nishan/Documents/input_logs/*.log
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
setup.kibana:
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5043"]
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

**logstash.yml**

```
pipeline.batch.size: 5
pipeline.batch.delay: 500
path.queue: /home/nishan/Documents/data_files
```

If I set queue.max_bytes: 1024mb in pipeline.yml, it works fine and all data will sent to elasticsearch and spring server. I guess that it could be the problem because of low queue size (15mb) I used. But in [logstash reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.7/persistent-queues.html#backpressure-persistent-queue) it said that it will handle back pressure by rejecting connections while queue is filled and it accept connections when queues have space. What could be the reason?

NOTE: 
I am using logstash and filebeat version 6.7 in ubuntu 18.04.